# How to remove path in my search code on vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I am very new to VB and I have an assignment which requires me to have search code in the program.The search code works but it shows the path of the file and I just want it to show the name of the txt file.

```
    Private Sub SearchOrdersToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SearchOrdersToolStripMenuItem.Click
    txtSearch.Visible = True
    Lblsearch.Visible = True
    Dim backslash As String() = FrmLogIn.FolderDirectory.Split("\")
    Dim filename As String = backslash(6)

    ListOfAllFileNames = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(FrmLogIn.FolderDirectory)
    TxtShoworders.Lines = ListOfAllFileNames

End Sub

  Private Sub txtSearch_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtSearch.TextChanged
    If txtSearch.Text = "" Then
        TxtShoworders.Lines = ListOfAllFileNames
        Return

    Else
        Dim SearchResults As New List(Of String)
        For Each currentFileName In ListOfAllFileNames
            If currentFileName.Contains(txtSearch.Text) Then
                SearchResults.Add(currentFileName)
            End If
        Next

        TxtShoworders.Lines = SearchResults.ToArray()

    End If


End Sub
```

[Link to what the program looks like and the directory showing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R7m22.png)

If anyone could help me with this that would be great, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to use [Path.GetFileName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename(v=vs.110).aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396&cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) for this, example:

```
SearchResults.Add(Path.GetFileName(currentFileName))
```

To keep your list of paths but only show the filenames, try this:

```
Private Sub SearchOrdersToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SearchOrdersToolStripMenuItem.Click
    txtSearch.Visible = True
    Lblsearch.Visible = True
    Dim backslash As String() = FrmLogIn.FolderDirectory.Split("\")
    Dim filename As String = backslash(6)

    ListOfAllFileNames = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(FrmLogIn.FolderDirectory)
    TxtShoworders.Lines = GetFileNames(ListOfAllFileNames)
End Sub

Private Sub txtSearch_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtSearch.TextChanged
    If txtSearch.Text = "" Then
        TxtShoworders.Lines = GetFileNames(ListOfAllFileNames)
        Return
    Else
        Dim SearchResults As New List(Of String)

        For Each currentFileName In ListOfAllFileNames
            If currentFileName.Contains(txtSearch.Text) Then
                SearchResults.Add(currentFileName)
            End If
        Next

        TxtShoworders.Lines = GetFileNames(SearchResults.ToArray())
    End If
End Sub

Private Function GetFileNames(Byval paths as String()) As String()
    Return paths.Select(Function(p) Path.GetFileName(p)).ToArray()
End Function
```

This will keep your `ListOfAllFileNames` containing the paths while only showing the file names using `GetFileNames`.

Comment: Could you tell me where I would put that piece of code because when I placed it in the program it made no difference.

Comment: Well you just replace this line `SearchResults.Add(currentFileName)`.

Comment: When I replace it with your code, it first shows the path with the name of the orders and then it removes the path as soon as I type in the search bar (TxtSearch) and then shows the name of the order (which I want). But, when I search something that is in the path then all the orders show even if the path is not visibly there.

Comment: I edited the answer, have a look and see if this is what you wanted.